# automatic linking of articles and groups

Tags: php, laravel, view, tags, grouping

I have articles that can contain different tags. For example, 5 pieces: (php, html, css, laravel, js) And I have groups that can also contain different tags. For example 4 pieces: (laravel, php, html, css)

I have already defined the relationships and it works. What I still lack is the linkage of articel to the group.

How can I show all posts in the group where the tags match?

Does anyone have an idea or can help me?

Post Model

```
  public function groups()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
  }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
    }
```

Tag Model

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Article', 'taggable');
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'taggable');
}
```

Group Model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since your question is updated I have seen a mistake in relationships**

change  **article_group** table name to **taggables**. Because laravel is doing some task on the basis of other table names. If you still want to use article_group then you will have to explicitly tell laravel about table names. 
Read HasRelationships.php (full path is given below) trait then you will have idea about how laravel is linking them automatically.

```
/your_project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php
```

**Yes** 
Solution to your requirement is **Many To Many Polymorphic Relations**

Read it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations.

You will create 4 tables as shown below and then create relationships in Models

```
articles
id - integer
name - string

groups
id - integer
name - string

tags
id - integer
name - string

taggables
tag_id - integer
taggable_id - integer
taggable_type - string
```

Relationship will be like this:

```
class Article extends Model
{

   public function tags()
   {
      return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'taggable');
   }
}
```

Inverse Relatioship will be like this:

```
class Tag extends Model
{

   public function articles()
   {
       return $this->morphedByMany('App\Article', 'taggable');
   }
   public function groups()
   {
       return $this->morphedByMany('App\Group', 'taggable');
   }
}
```

Now you can get tags of Article like this:

```
$article = App\Article::find(1);

foreach ($article->tags as $tag) {
    //
}
```

**Attaching Articles To The Groups is As Follows:**

```
$article = App\Article::find(1);
$group = App\Group::find(1);
$article->groups()->sync($group->id);

Read this for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that does not help me any further. I have completed my question

Comment: As you have done many to many relationships then you should know Linkage of article to the group is simple . I am sure you have created a pivot table article_group for articles and groups. To link them, you can use attach,detach or sync() methods according to your requirements

Comment: yes the relationships are done. I do not know how to link the articles to the groups, 
the table article_group is empty

Comment: Okay let me update my answer to show you how to to this

Comment: You are refering wrong table name for this relationship. article_group should not be there. You should create taggables table and laravel does some work based on the table names and relationship types. If you will use article_group then you will have to explicitly tell laravel about table names so that it can pick them and relate correctly.

Comment: I deleted the table name article_group in the model. But I do not know how to link the right group with the right posts. How can I link the right groups and posts with the same tags?

Comment: See lart portion of my answer. Anyhow, support you are creating an  article from admin section, you will write article content and select tags that you want to attach with this article. Then in controller, you will save new article and attach tags in this way $article->tags()->sync($tag->id); or $article->tags()->sync($tagIds);

Comment: thank you for your help. But that's not my problem. I save the tags for the article and the tags for the groups. It works. What I miss is the linking of the groups with the matching articles that have the same tags. so that I can load all the articles into the group.

Comment: I give you an example:  load all posts which "array group tags" = "array post tags"